# turn monitor off cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I know the way for making whole system to sleep.

But I hope to turn off monitor programmatically while os is working
(not whole system sleep)

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe those links could help you:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/191807-sleep-display.html
http://explanatorygap.net/2009/01/31/a-screensaver-to-send-your-display-to-sleep/